# How to return a static/dynamic JSON/XML response in a Flowgear workflow using API binding

Tags: integration, flowgear

I am trying to return a simple JSON/XML response after API binding to a workflow. I am getting a JSON response as follows.

`{ "FirstMatch": null, "status": true, "statusMessage": "", "StepCount": 2, "progress": "[]", "enginePerf": "{\"setup\":46.8126,\"execute\":0.0,\"strike\":0.0}", "taskStartId": "ad1312ad-2492-4634-a66d-1123a478fd2192ac70", "apiPerf": "{\"execute\":78.1357}" }`

Instead of this, Is it possible to return a custom JSON/XML message in a workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your message above, it seems that you have not connected your desired response to the variable bar `FgResponseBody` property. The Variable bar comes with a bunch of defined properties for cases like this one.

You can achieve this by following the below steps:

1. Add another Variable Bar to your Workflow, close to the end of your workflow for readability.
2. Click on the + to add a property to the Variable bar and click on the dropdown within the box you would usually type the property name in. You will be presented with a list of defined Flowgear properties, which includes `FgResponseBody` and many others for API inputs and outputs. (Screenshot for reference below)

[image: Flowgear Defined Properties]

3. Once you have added the new property and selected `FgResponseBody` from the API Outputs within the dropdown, you will also need to add `FgResponseContentType` and `FgResponseCode` to the new Variable bar.

With the above in place, we can now set up our workflow to output a custom message from anywhere in our workflow. Connect your custom message output to the input of the new `FgResponseBody` property and use either `application/json` in the `FgResponseContentType` property if you wish to return a JSON response, or use `application/xml` if you wish to respond with XML. You can also return custom HTTP status using the `FgResponseCode` defined property.

Below is a screenshot of a small example API workflow where I have set up a Formatter node for success and error. Both outputs are connected to `FgResponseBody`, but in this case, only one will be pushed into the response, depending on the outcome of the IF node checking for success.

[Sample API workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbIWW.png)

It is also worth noting that it is important to remember to catch all errors within the workflow and once caught, you can route them to the appropriate node to provide a meaningful response to your API consumer.

[Here is the link to our article about APIs in Flowgear.](https://help.flowgear.net/articles/api/api)

Please feel free to have a look through our [help center](https://help.flowgear.net/) as well. We have many articles and examples on all things Flowgear. You can also get directly to a node's help article by clicking on the dropdown arrow on any node, and then selecting *Help for this Node*.